# How to prevent Ubuntu from suspend

Tags: suspend, automatic

I have a problem with automatic suspend in my ubuntu. I have following settings

[image: image with power settings]

but even that I have plugged computer in it is suspended

[image: message]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Caffeine Gnome shell extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/

If you don't have extensions installed [this link](https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/05/how-to-install-and-use-gnome-shell-extensions-in-ubuntu/) shows you how.

You will need to:

```
 sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

after which you can select the required extension.